# Get all binded ip addresses

Tags: 14.04, network-manager, ethernet, ifconfig

I have configured my network card eth0 to use 3 IPs, such as 192.168.1.10, 10.0.0.10 and  192.168.0.10.

[image]

After network restart, `ifconfig` is showing only one IP ie, 192.168.1.10. But I can ping between those IPs.

How do I get all binded IPs on eth0?

Comment: From a terminal, try `$ ip addr`.  What output does that give you?

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 amazing!! Now I can see all my IPs. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Excellent!  Converting comment to answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a terminal session, try using `ip` with `addr`:

```
$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:4d:89:99:87 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.100/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::2e0:4dff:fe89:9987/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

From the `man ip` page:

```
ip - show / manipulate routing, devices, policy routing and tunnels

IP - COMMAND SYNTAX
   OBJECT
       address
              - protocol (IP or IPv6) address on a device.

       addrlabel
              - label configuration for protocol address selection.
```